# How to generate FilterExpression without hard-coding the attribute names?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I know one can scan or query like this:

```
response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('first_name').begins_with('J') &
                     Attr('account_type').eq('super_user') )
```

How do I do this without hard coding the attribute names?
To clarify, given such dictionary, I wish to table scan as such;

```
attr_dict = {"foo":42, "bar":52}

response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('foo').eq(42) &
                         Attr('bar').eq(52) )
```

If it's a sql, although one wouldn't do it, they can do

```
"select * from table where {} = {} and {} = {}".format(a,b,x,y).
```

The problem I'm having is how would I & the two using a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the FilterExpression by looping over the entries in the dictionary. You can use boolean logic to combine individual expressions as follows (just build the filter expression string manually):

```
foo = 42 AND bar = 52
```

Comment: Can you show me the whole syntax? Does FilterExpression accept a string?

Comment: I was able to achieved what I was looking for. FilterExpression does accept a string. It seems like the values must come from `ExpressionAttributeValues`. Thanks